# Can't generate new NumericUpDown in forms C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to create a new `NumericUpDown` form when I click a button. For some reason the `NumericUpDown` that I generated won't show up. Am I missing something stupid here?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    NumericUpDown n = new NumericUpDown();

    n.Location = new Point(200, 12);
    n.Name = "num";
    n.Size = new Size(83, 20);
    //n.TabIndex = 5;
    //n.Show();
}
```

I am most likely missing something very stupid, but i can't find it and i would appreciate your help.

Comment: You need to add it to the form.

Comment: A.k.a `this.Controls.Add(n);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing [`Controls.Add(n)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controls(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    NumericUpDown n = new NumericUpDown();

    n.Location = new Point(200, 12);
    n.Name = "num";
    n.Size = new Size(83, 20);
    Controls.Add(n);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I checked Form.designer.cs but I could not find that line.